# Shell script while loop inside a for loop

Tags: shell, tcsh

with tcsh, I want to print "Hello" for each x,y, z, e, and f. But with the following script, it only prints x. Can someone tell me how to print "Hello" also for y, z, e, and f?

```
#! /bin/tcsh -f
set arr=(x y z e f)

set j = 0
foreach i ($arr)
echo $i
   while ($j < 5)

     echo "Hello"
     @ j++
    end
end
```

The result is:
x
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
y
z
e
f

Comment: you are only initializing the 'j' iterator variable to 0 one time.  You need. to reinitialize the. variable to 0 inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the initialization of the 'j' variable inside the foreach loop:

```
#! /bin/tcsh -f
set arr=(x y z e f)

foreach i ($arr)
    echo $i
    set j = 0
    while ($j < 5)
            echo "Hello"
            @ j++
    end
end
```

Output:

```
$ ./s.sh
x
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
y
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
z
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
e
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
f
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```